# WooCommerce: Adding product variation description to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a single product that is called on the homepage using the product shortcode `[product sku=""]`. The product has variations, with each variation having a different description.

I'm having trouble having the variation descriptions come up as a user selects a different option from the drop-down.

Can anyone assist with a solution? Thank you in advance!

PS. Variation description appears well on product single pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to wordpress admin panel.
2. Go to Produts > All Products
3. Select a particular Product
4. Click "Quick Edit"

There is a field Called "Slug"
Rename it

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time to reply and pardon my ignorance, but how does changing the slug get the product variation description to appear on the [product] shortcode on the homepage?

Comment: HI Lina, Can you explain the problem again with screenshots. It will easy to identify your problem clearly

Comment: Hello! Thank you for trying to assist. I have uploaded some screenshots here: https://imgur.com/a/XhWhC

Just to add on, this isn't a single product page. Rather it is an embedded product on the homepage, placed here with the [product] shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Using [product_page] shortcode instead of [product] shortcode solved it! Now full product details including product variation descriptions appear.